# Styling background-color for div When div height changes

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the follow ASP.Net MVC razor code.

```
@{
    foreach (var note in Model.Notes)
    {
        <div class="row data-area" style="margin-bottom:5px !important">
            <div class="small-2 columns magmalabel" style="background-color:#01466d;">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => note.NoteTypeId)
            </div>
            <div class="small-10 columns">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => note.Notes)
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

This works, but occasionally, the second column word wraps due to the length, this is by design, but the first div that displays:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => note.NoteTypeId)
```

does not get the correct formatting as it does not color the second row.

I know that this is a height issue as so far the only way I have managed to do this is by setting the height property to twice the size in the Chrome console.

```
                <div class="small-2 columns magmalabel" style="background-color:#01466d;height:50px;">
```

*In Chrome, a single height equals 25px's*

I have looked on SO and seen many solutions, but so far none has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Had to resort to some jQuery to sort this out.

Added a placeholder class, rowHeading, to the markup as below:

```
<div class="row data-area" style="margin-bottom:5px !important">
    <div class="small-2 columns magmalabel rowHeading" style="background-color:#01466d;">
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => note.NoteTypeId)
    </div>
    <div class="small-10 columns">
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => note.Notes)
    </div>
</div>
```

Then simply added the following jQuery script:

```
  $('.rowheading').each(function () {
        var parentHeight = $(this).parent().height();
        $(this).height(parentHeight);
    });
```

This enabled the browser to set the row height for all divs on the page to correctly format the height.